# write acces to function slot (other than defun)

Tags: common-lisp

The `defun` macro "stores" a function *object* in the function *slot* of a symbol, e.g.:
`(defun f () "Hello.")` 

The function that prints "Hello" is now stored in the function slot of the symbol `f`.
(And can be retrieved via `#'f`.)
Is there another way (other than `defun`) to write/"store" a function object in the function slot of a symbol?
Because something like `(setf minus #'-)` only would store the function object in the *value* slot of the symbol `minus`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there another way (other than defun) to write/"store" a function object in the function slot of a symbol?

You can use [`symbol-function`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_1.htm#symbol-function):

```
(setf (symbol-function 'f) (lambda () "Bye."))
(f)  ; => "Bye."
(defun g () "Hello again.")
(setf (symbol-function 'f) (symbol-function 'g))
(f)  ; => "Hello again."
```

Another possibility is to use [`fdefinition`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fdefin.htm#fdefinition):

```
(setf (fdefinition 'f) (lambda () "Bye again.")
(f)  ; => "By again"
```

They are almost equivalent. The main difference is that `symbol-function` requires an argument which *must* be a symbol, while `fdefinition` accepts a function name, which can be also a list (see the [glossary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_name)).

Comment: also `fdefinition`

Comment: @Renzo @sds Thank you! I always thought `symbol-function` ist only some kind of getter. But according to your example it can be used as a location in a setter as well. Going to check out the HyperSpec regarding `symbol-value`. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that this only works for top level (global) bindings. It will ignore lexical bindings created in the function namespace with `flet` and `labels`